# I want to find average of this loop

Tags: python, loops, average, head

```
import random
player = ['H','T']
player_win = []
for x in range(10):
    
    while True:
        random.shuffle(player)
        #print(player)
        if player[(0)] == 'H' :
            player_win.append(1)
            #print(player_win)
            continue
        else :
            player_win.append('LOST')
            #print('PLAYER LOST')
        break
```

I'm new in python and right now as a task I'm making a logic where I need to find the average of this loop so I could decide at what minimum value the game should be put so that the dealer is always in profit

Well actually this is my own logic where I don't know if I'm correct or not but overall I want that know  at what price of the game I should set so I make profit
price = ?
player_price = 1
if win double the player_price
else 0
again ask to play or not
if not break
if yes
again toss and now
if win double the previous player_win
else 0
So in the whole game find what the average price of the game should be and it should solely done by computer only (No, user input intended)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Instead of appending the string of 'LOST', instead append 0 as a loss, you can then get the average of the player_win list.

```py
import random
player = ['H','T'] 
player_win = [] 
for x in range(10):
    while True:
        random.shuffle(player)
        #print(player)
        if player[(0)] == 'H' :
            player_win.append(1)
            print(player_win)
            continue
        else :
            player_win.append(0)
            print('PLAYER LOST')
        break
# get the average of the list
average = sum(player_win) / len(player_win)
print(f"Average Wins: {average}")
```